# Powershell run export-mailbox script from batch file

Tags: batch-file, powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to run a batch file which runs powershell script (Export-mailbox -identity admin -pstFolderPath \srv02\d$\test)

I have been running the export-mailbox command manually to export 20 mailboxes. I would like to make this process as a script so I can run it everyday to make a backup of all mailboxes with pst files.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list the mailboxes you want to export into a csv file then import the csv file in the batch to export each mail item.  Something like...

```
$Mailboxes=Import-Csv \\srv02\d$\test\mailboxes.csv
$Mailboxes | ForEach-Object{Export-mailbox -identity admin -pstFolderPath \srv02\d$\test}
```